# CSS: Text overlay on images while hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've read several tutorials and forums include this and other sources on how to create an hover state description overlay over images. I have also successfully created a version of it. However there is one problem: its not responsive (or it breaks gracefully).

```
   <div class="section">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <p><b>1 unit Mathematics extension</b></p>
                <img src="img/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail">
                <p id="overlay">Placerat massa ut est, in, .</p>
            </div>
        </li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note*: the reason why i have it in a list is that on desktop and tablet view i want 3 images to appear across the page.

my relevant CSS is:

```
.section ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

.section li{
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.section img{
    width:90%;
}

#overlay{
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
    bottom: 127px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

My problem is the #overlay css, Im trying to align the bottom of the overlay to the bottom edge of the image. however when i do a percentage e.g. bottom: x% it does not work, which forces me to use a fixed px. However when i do this, based on the width of the window the height of the overlay changes and sometimes it results in the bottom edge of the overlay not aligned with the bottom of the edge.

Is there are way to work around this using css and html only?

if anyone is able to provide some input that would be much appreciated it!

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: A fiddle would would be very useful.

Comment: @knox what is a fiddle?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/ and corresponding answers..

Answer (score 2):

use `z-index` for `#overlay`

```
#overlay{
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;

    bottom: 50px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index:1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vx6ET/2/)

check the demo and expand and collapse the result window to know the reponsiveness

Comment: Hi Sajad, I had a look at the demo link, this is exactly what I'm getting. However I want the overlay to be bottom aligned with the image and I need it to be responsive. if this is not possible in CSS then I will definitely consider javascript. its just that its a small project and i didn't want to make it too complicated.

Comment: @user3388149 i dont know if your asking the same as what you intend,but as what you asked the overlay is perfectly bottom aligned,will be bottom aligned in what ever screen sizes

Comment: i probably didnt explain it very well. In your demo link the line: #overlay{bottom:50px;}. This CSS code fixes the overlay to a particular position. when the window resizes the overlay height value changes which breaks the presentation. im trying to get this effect: http://maketea.co.uk/2013/12/16/smooth-text-overlays-with-css-transforms.html but not overal the whole image just a portion of it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Sometime jQuery is very easy help us incompare of tricky CSS

### check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34U58/1/)

jQuery (library 1.7.2)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").mouseover(function(){
        $("#overlay").css("z-index","9999");
    });
    $("img").mouseout(function(){
        $("#overlay").css("z-index","-1");
    });
});
```

Comment: He did ask for only Html and Css.

Comment: @SaintGerbil: that is what is my answer..!!